# Dynamic style imports using Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a web application using Angular and my goal would be to generate a style using sass according to some environment variables in my code.

For instance :
style.scss

```
import "myVariables.scss"
import "{{ScssClient}}" // variable overload

/// my style ...///
```

somewhere in a TS file :

```
let ScssClient = "www.downloadfile.com/myscssfile";
```

I know SASS does not support variable interpolation .

Is there any workaround to achieve my goal ?

Comment: Why not add a `production` wrapper on the body ? Could solve your issue ... Otherwise I'm not sure you can do that.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what are you trying to achieve... Creating a css file on a REST request? If you just want to create multiple themes, that is usually done with theme classes on the `body`. If you want to generate something based on a user form, you can look at this [example](https://github.com/Kibibit/kibibit-code-editor/blob/master/app/models/colorThemeService.js). Basically, you can change the import with a templating engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS variables if your application requirements support them.

Check https://medium.freecodecamp.org/everything-you-need-to-know-about-css-variables-c74d922ea855

In particular in a service you could override them in this way:

```
function handleThemeUpdate(e) {
  switch(e.target.value) {
    case 'dark': 
      root.style.setProperty('--bg', 'black')
      root.style.setProperty('--bg-text', 'white')
      break
    case 'calm': 
       root.style.setProperty('--bg', '#B3E5FC')
       root.style.setProperty('--bg-text', '#37474F')
      break
    case 'light':
      root.style.setProperty('--bg', 'white')
      root.style.setProperty('--bg-text', 'black')
      break
  }
}
```

Answer it's not exactly related with your question, but it's a possible hint :)